# Mule 4 Dataweave: Array from script output to JSON

Tags: dataweave, mule4

After a script module execution, I get the output below:

```
[
"0": [
"0": ["A","B","C"],
"1": ["D","E","F"]
],
"1": [
"0": ["A","B","C"],
"1": ["D","E","F"],
"2": ["G","H","I"]
],
"2": [
"0": ["A","B","C"],
"1": ["D","E","F"],
"2": ["G","H","I"]
]
]
```

And I would like to get only the values, not the keys. So the expected output would be:

```
[
   [
      ["A","B","C"],
      ["D","E","F"]
   ],
   [
      ["A","B","C"],
      ["D","E","F"],
      ["G","H","I"]
   ],
   [
      ["A","B","C"],
      ["D","E","F"],
      ["G","H","I"]
   ]
]
```

I tried to use the map function and the valuesOf function, but without any luck.

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the input as well?

Comment: @Pierre It seems the output from the script execution is incorrect. It violates all the json rules

Comment: The input is not a valid JSON. It seems to be an array with keys which is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input and the first childs are really objects, you can use pluck() at the top level to extract as an array of objects, then map each of the childs to use pluck() again.

Input:

```json
{
    "0": {
        "0": ["A","B","C"],
        "1": ["D","E","F"]
    },
    "1": {
        "0": ["A","B","C"],
        "1": ["D","E","F"],
        "2": ["G","H","I"]
    },
    "2": {
        "0": ["A","B","C"],
        "1": ["D","E","F"],
        "2": ["G","H","I"]
    }
}
```

Script:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---
payload 
    pluck $ 
    flatMap 
        ($ pluck ((value, key, index) -> value))
```

Output:

```json
[
  [
    [
      "A",
      "B",
      "C"
    ],
    [
      "D",
      "E",
      "F"
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      "A",
      "B",
      "C"
    ],
    [
      "D",
      "E",
      "F"
    ],
    [
      "G",
      "H",
      "I"
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      "A",
      "B",
      "C"
    ],
    [
      "D",
      "E",
      "F"
    ],
    [
      "G",
      "H",
      "I"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you! I could not make it work myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option supposing the output looks like this

```
[
  {
    "0": {
      "0": ["A","B","C"],
      "1": ["D","E","F"]
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "0": ["A","B","C"],
      "1": ["D","E","F"],
      "2": ["G","H","I"]
    }
  },
  {
    "2": {
      "0": ["A","B","C"],
      "1": ["D","E","F"],
      "2": ["G","H","I"]
    }
  }
]
```

this script turns it into your desired output

```
payload map (valuesOf($) flatMap valuesOf($))
```

output

```
[
  [
    ["A","B","C"],
    ["D","E","F"]
  ],
  [
    ["A","B","C"],
    ["D","E","F"],
    ["G","H","I"]
  ],
  [
    ["A","B","C"],
    ["D","E","F"],
    ["G","H","I"]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you! I could not make it work myself :)